# $f(x)=\frac{x^3}{1-x^2}$. When is $f(x)$ increasing, and when is $f(x)$ decreasing?

Tags: derivatives

I have $f(x)$ and need to find the intervals when it is is increasing and when it is deacreasing. I found out that it is not defined at $x=-1$ and $x=1$, and it made me unsecure. When I write the intervals, do I need to exclude these points, or not because they are not in the domain? And do they mean strictly increasing or just monotonically increasing?

**Is it correct to say that it is increasing on $[-sqrt(3),sqrt(3)]\{-1,1}]$ and decreasing on $(-inf,-sqrt(3)] U [sqrt(3),inf)$?**

Comment: If you use the derivative, you will find the points at which the derivative is $0$. Add to these the points $-1$ and $1$. That will give you all the points where the original function **could** (it need not) change from increasing to decreasing, or vice-versa. Check all these points. Life is made easier by the fact that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so there is a kind of symmetry, the part with $x\lt 0$ is obtained by rotating the part with $x\gt 0$ by $180$ degrees about the origin.

Comment: Yes, so do I need to say that it is increasing on (-sqrt(3),-1)U(-1,0)U(0,1)U(1,sqrt(3))?

Answer (score 1):

When you take the derivative you should find that the derivative is not defined at -1 and 1.

For your second question: Strictly increasing functions have $f(x)>f(y)$ implies $x>y$ and vice versa, and $f(x)=f(y)$ means $x=y$. Monotonic functions do not have this second part, so it could be constant on an interval then continue to increase after.